# Retornar dados de outra função dentro de uma diretiva ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma função que retorna um array dentro de uma diretiva `ng-repeat`, até aqui tudo normal,

O que eu quero saber como trazer dados de outra função que faz outra consulta, quero trazer dentro da `div` com `ng-repeat`, porem somente um registro

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa.. Consegue mostrar o que você tem de código hoje para ver o que podemos ajudar?

Comment: Não só mostrar o código, explicar melhor sua duvida.